# Separate radio button groups in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutControl which I fill dynamically with radio buttons. There are four columns. I want radio buttons from columns 1-3 to form groups in each row and radio buttons in column 4 to form a single group. In other words horizontal groups in each row and one vertical in last column. How can I do that?

Comment: No, this is not possible. The [radiobutton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a 'group' property, unfortunately. Of course the grouping should also be clearly __visible__ to the user.. - So you will need to add two panels instead..

Comment: I suppose I need not two panels but a panel for each row.

Comment: Yes, I didn't catch the four rows..

Comment: If you want the RadioButtons to stay in the same "grid" positions as before, I think you'd have to add Panels and make them "span" the rows/columns, then add TableLayoutPanels **inside each Panel** and set them up as individual rows/columns to put your RadioButtons into.  If you don't need them to be as rigid in their placement, then use FlowLayoutPanels as suggested by Backs.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it works perfectly. As for the vertical group there was no need to do anything because the main panel groups them.

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way is to put into every cell of table some groupping control (panel, groupBox, flowLayoutPanel, ...) and add radio buttons into this group.

Comment: I think I need to reduce number of columns to two and place one panel in each cell of first row and then add three radio buttons to each panel.

Comment: @grzegorz advice you to use FlowLayoutPanel for dynamic adding control - it's very suitable control

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know which row and column of each `RadioButton` (like when creating one name it rdb2_3 mean it belong to row 2 column 3 of the `TableLayoutControl`), add `CheckedChanged` event to all of them like:

```
    rdb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rdb_CheckedChanged);

    void rdb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
            // Check if this RadioButton belong to column 4th so it belong to the column group
            if (((RadioButton)sender).Name.Substring(((RadioButton)sender).Name.Length - 1) == "4")
            {
                // Set Checked = false for all RadioButton in column 4 except this one
            }
            else
            {
                // Set Checked = false for all RadioButton in this RadioButton's row 4 except this one
            }
    }
```